# How can I check if file exists with exception handeling

Tags: php

I am trying to use exception handling in case  a file does not exists. For example when I run the model method and pass a string usr (which I know there is no file with that name) . It gives me the following error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Usr.php was not found' in /app/core/controller.php on line 14
```

I can't figure out whats wrong here. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Below is my code. Thanks alot!

```
class Controllers{
    public function model($model){
         if(!file_exists("../app/models/".$model.".php")) {
              throw new exception("{$model}.php was not found");
         }
         try {
              require ("../app/models/".$model.".php");
         } catch(Exception $e) {
              echo  $e->getMessage();
         }
         return new $model();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't throw an exception without catching it; this automatically causes the PHP script to crash. So, you need to surround your entire function in the try-catch block, or the "model not found" exception will be uncaught. Your code should be something like this:

```
<?php
class Controllers {
    public function model($model){
        try {
            if (!file_exists("../app/models/".$model.".php")) {
                throw new Exception("{$model}.php was not found");
            }
            require ("../app/models/".$model.".php");
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return new $model();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys! I found out I needed to use the try/catch blocks in the file where my method is being invoked

Example..

```
class Home extends Controllers{
    public function index($name = ""){
      try{
        $user = $this->model('Usr');
      }catch (Exception $e){
         echo  $e->getMessage();
      }
        //var_dump($user);
    }
```